# Is it permissible to work in the company that distributes movies?

Tags: halal-haram, movies

I am working as a Software Developer in an IT firm. There business is a subscription-based Internet TV service offering Asian movies, TV shows and music videos.

I am developing Softwares for that company. Is it halal for me to work there?

If not should i quit the job right away or should I search for new job while working in the company?

Similarly, what about my wages that I earned until now?

Answer (score 1):

Asalamualaikum brother i am glad you have asked this question i have the similar doubt so i asked to aalim of my nearby masjid he said its haram
Since although you are helping by working that company who is doing haram
so please ask first to the aalim before taking any decissions

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with you working there, because you are not sure that the very thing you produce is used for Haram. Therefore, you are free to continue working there. By the way, your earning as of today is all Halal.

Answer (score 0):

Brother as you mentioned it distribute movies, tv shows and the like which the majority promote and show things that are against quran and Islam. So it is haram for you to work there. I would suggest you to find the other job immediately.
May Allah help you in finding the suitable job that is halal.